# Error: undefined index?

Tags: php, mysql, database, indexing, undefined

I get this array from a function (var_dump()):

```
...{ [0]=> string(7) "user_id" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "user_id" } [2]...
```

When I try to separate the values with:

$var2 = $var['user_id']

I get the error "undefined index 'user_id'", even though, as you can see, the name of the value is "user_id", and I've checked my database a hundred times, and that IS the name of the index.

What other possible sources of error are there?

I appreciate any help!
Thank you in advance!

```
function get_subscribitions($user)
{

$user = mysql_real_escape_string ($user);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `subscribe` WHERE subscriber = '$user'";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);

  $rows = array();

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $rows[] = $row;
  }

  mysql_free_result($result);

  return $rows;
```

Can anyone pinpoint where in the above code, I make the mistake leading to this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: 'user_id' is not key but the value! Who and how to build the array?

Comment: @JellyBelly Thanks, but how can I tell what the key is?

Comment: how to build this array?

Comment: how do you set this array? paste some code

Comment: @KA_lin Do you see something in the code, that might be an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array key 0 contains a string called `'user_id'` but there is no key named `'user_id'`, hence why you're getting the error.

I suggest you take a look at how you're compiling this data (query results perhaps?).

Comment: Would you please take a look at the updated question, and maybe point me in the direction of what I'm doing wrong when setting up the array?

Answer (score 1):

[0] is the index and the data is "user_id"

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken. The structure of the array is like this:

```
array:
    [0] => array:
        [0] => "user_id"
    [1] => array:
        [0] => "user_id"
```

You need to access it like this: `$var[0][0]` and you will get `user_id`. Most likely you did something wrong when setting up the array.

Comment: I've updated the question a bit, would you mind taking a look and point me in the direction of the error I'm making setting up the array?

Comment: This is definitely strange. I would expect the result to be quite different from the dump you posted. Are you quite sure those two are related?

Comment: It worked out eventually. It had to do with the rows[] = row config.

Answer (score 0):

the index is [0]. I don't think you have this structured correctly. The index is the left side of the declaration, the value is the right. You have assigned all values to "user_id" with incremental index.

Answer (score 0):

`user_id` is not an array key (that can be accessed by `[]`), it is an value.

But you can use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-search.php)

```
$index = array_search('user_id', $your_array);

var_dump(  $your_array[$index]  );
```

Answer (score 0):

error because the `user_id` is not an `index` it's a value having `index 0`